# Getting an error while sending a json payload in quartz scheduler

Tags: json, postman, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to send a json payload in quartz scheduler. I have the header set to Content-type:application/json, but for some reason my json string is throwing an error: Uncaught error, unexpected token in json.

The original json that I'm sending to a graphql service looks like this:

```
  {
    GetAllAuthors{
      id
      name
    }
   }
```

But to make it work in quartz, I need to mimic a rest API call, which is why I tried using the following:

```
   { "query":{{""{\nGetAllAuthors {\nid\nname\n}\n\n}""}} }
```

The above is also giving me the "Uncaught error, unexpected token in json" error. Is there something that I'm missing or overlooking?

PS: I tried using an online json formatter and when I try to validate the above json, I get the following error:

```
     Error: Parse error on line 2:
      { "query": {      {           "" {\               nGetA
        --------------^
        Expecting 'STRING', '}', got '{'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out by testing through Mozilla's network tab - the correct format is:

{"query":"{\n GetAllAuthors{\n id\n name\n}\n}\n","variables":null, "operationName":null}

Answer (score 1):

That's not valid Json. This is how it might look if it were:

```
 {
    "GetAllAuthors": [
        "id",
        "name"
    ]
 }
```

but I suspect you're trying for something like this:

```
 {
    "GetAllAuthors": {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "James Brown"
    }
 }
```

Play here until you get it right: https://jsonlint.com/

Edit: I've not worked with GraphQL, but this page shows how a (non JSON) GraphQL query might be transferred over Http by POSTing JSON or GETting using querystrings: https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/

Comment: my application is a graphql app with graphiql enabled; when I invoke my graphql service from the browser that is the format I use since my query is actually a mutation that updates a database; in other words - I just have the query name and the field names only, without any values.